# MPI Fortran compiler optimization error

Tags: fortran, mpi, compiler-optimization

Despite having written long, heavily parallelized codes with complicated send/receives over three dimensional arrays, this simple code with a two dimensional array of integers has got me at my wits end. I combed stackoverflow for possible solutions and found one that resembled slightly with the issue I am having:

[Boost.MPI: What's received isn't what was sent!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024940/boost-mpi-whats-received-isnt-what-was-sent)

However the solutions seem to point the looping segment of code as the culprit for overwriting sections of the memory. But this one seems to act even stranger. Maybe it is a careless oversight of some simple detail on my part. The problem is with the below code:

```
program main
implicit none

include 'mpif.h'

integer :: i, j
integer :: counter, offset
integer :: rank, ierr, stVal
integer, dimension(10, 10) :: passMat, prntMat      !! passMat CONTAINS VALUES TO BE PASSED TO prntMat

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)

counter = 0
offset = (rank + 1)*300
do j = 1, 10
    do i = 1, 10
        prntMat(i, j) = 10                          !! prntMat OF BOTH RANKS CONTAIN 10
        passMat(i, j) = offset + counter            !! passMat OF rank=0 CONTAINS 300..399 AND rank=1 CONTAINS 600..699
        counter = counter + 1
    end do
end do

if (rank == 1) then
    call MPI_SEND(passMat(1:10, 1:10), 100, MPI_INTEGER, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)    !! SEND passMat OF rank=1 to rank=0
else
    call MPI_RECV(prntMat(1:10, 1:10), 100, MPI_INTEGER, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stVal, ierr)
    do i = 1, 10
        print *, prntMat(:, i)
    end do
end if

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
end program main
```

When I compile the code with mpif90 with no flags and run it on my machine with mpirun -np 2, I get the following output with wrong values in the first four indices of the array:

0           0         400           0         604         605         606         607         608         609
         610         611         612         613         614         615         616         617         618         619
         620         621         622         623         624         625         626         627         628         629
         630         631         632         633         634         635         636         637         638         639
         640         641         642         643         644         645         646         647         648         649
         650         651         652         653         654         655         656         657         658         659
         660         661         662         663         664         665         666         667         668         669
         670         671         672         673         674         675         676         677         678         679
         680         681         682         683         684         685         686         687         688         689
         690         691         692         693         694         695         696         697         698         699

However, when I compile it with the same compiler but with the -O3 flag on, I get the correct output:

600         601         602         603         604         605         606         607         608         609
         610         611         612         613         614         615         616         617         618         619
         620         621         622         623         624         625         626         627         628         629
         630         631         632         633         634         635         636         637         638         639
         640         641         642         643         644         645         646         647         648         649
         650         651         652         653         654         655         656         657         658         659
         660         661         662         663         664         665         666         667         668         669
         670         671         672         673         674         675         676         677         678         679
         680         681         682         683         684         685         686         687         688         689
         690         691         692         693         694         695         696         697         698         699

This error is machine dependent. This issue turns up only on my system running Ubuntu 14.04.2, using OpenMPI 1.6.5

I tried this on other systems running RedHat and CentOS and the code ran well with and without the -O3 flag. Curiously those machines use an older version of OpenMPI - 1.4

I am guessing that the -O3 flag is performing some odd optimization that is modifying the manner in which arrays are being passed between the processes.

I also tried other versions of array allocation. The above code uses explicit shape arrays. With assumed shape and allocated arrays I am receiving equally, if not more bizarre results, with some of them seg-faulting. I tried using Valgrind to trace the origin of these seg-faults, but I still haven't gotten the hang of getting Valgrind to not give false positives when running with MPI programs.

I believe that resolving the difference in performance of the above code will help me understand the tantrums of my other codes as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This code has really gotten me questioning if all the other MPI codes I wrote are sound at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Fortran 90 interface to MPI reveals a mismatch in your call to `MPI_RECV`

```
      call MPI_RECV(prntMat(1:10, 1:10), 100, MPI_INTEGER, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, stVal, ierr)
                                                                                            1
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_recv’ at (1)
```

This is because the status variable `stVal` is an `integer` scalar, rather than an array of `MPI_STATUS_SIZE`.  The F77 interface (`include 'mpif.h'`) to `MPI_RECV` is:

> ```
> INCLUDE ’mpif.h’
> MPI_RECV(BUF, COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM, STATUS, IERROR)
> <type>    BUF(*)
> INTEGER    COUNT, DATATYPE, SOURCE, TAG, COMM
> INTEGER    STATUS(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), IERROR
> ```

Changing

```
integer :: rank, ierr, stVal
```

to

```
integer :: rank, ierr, stVal(mpi_status_size)
```

produces a program that works as expected, tested with gfortran 5.1 and OpenMPI 1.8.5.

Using the F90 interface (`use mpi` vs `include "mpif.h"`) lets the compiler detect the mismatched arguments at compile time rather than producing confusing runtime problems.

Comment: A very common error. Unfortunately, the interface is often not explicit even with the mpi module http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049648/mpi-recv-changes-the-value-of-count (maybe a direct duplicate?)

Comment: @casey: thanks a lot! But switching to 'use mpi' is not raising error for me on gfortran 4.8.2, ompi 1.6.5. And I still am curious how the optimisation flag glossed over it.

Comment: @RoshanSam read what Hristo Illiev writes in my link. The optimizations change the locations of the variables located on the stack. He also explains why you do not get any warning even with `use mpi `.

Comment: @VladimirF his comments are helpful, thanks.. I'm surprised that stackoverflow didn't point me to the above question when I was repeatedly searching for the solution. Probably because though the underlying problem was same, the symptoms were different. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I will probably mark these questions as duplicates. Any objections?

Comment: Since the comments on the other question can provide a bit more insight to anyone else who comes to this post with the same problem, go on..

Comment: @VladimirF Go for it.